# Scala Spark - how to iterate fields in a Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

My Dataframe has several columns with different types (string, double, Map, array, etc).

I need to perform some operation in certain column types and I am looking for a nice way to identify the field type and then do the proper action

types: `String|Double|Map<String,Int>|...`

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|myString1 |myDouble1|     myMap1                   | ...otherTypes                          
|---------------------------------------------------------------
|"string_1"|  123.0  |{"str1Map":1,"str2":2, "str31inmap": 31} |...
|"string_2"|  456.0  |{"str2Map":2,"str22":2, "str32inmap": 32}|...
|"string_3"|  789.0  |{"str3Map":3,"str23":2, "str33inmap": 33}|...
|---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Iterating the dataframe fields and printing: `df.schema.fields.foreach { println }`

outputs:

```
StructField(myString1,StringType,true)
StructField(myDouble1,DoubleType,false)
StructField(myMap1,MapType(StringType,IntType,false),true)
...
StructField(myStringList,ArrayType(StringType,true),true)
```

So, my  idea is to iterate through the fields and in case is one of the types that I need to perform an operation (e.g. on the Map type), then I know the field name/column and action to take.

```
 df.schema.fields.foreach { f =>
     val fName = ?get the name
     val fType = ?get the Type
     print("Name{} Type:{}".format(fName , fType))

      // case type is Map do action X
      // case type is Stringdo action Y
      // ...

    }
```

Does this approach makes sense to detect the field types on my dataframe and then perform different on the df fields, depending on their type?
How to get it to work?

Comment: I think you need `dtype` method 
here is what you can do is

`df.dtype.foreach{ pairData =>
val fName = pairData._1
val fType = pairData._2
//Your code here
}`

Comment: this way, the val _fName_ and _fType_ are empty :/

Comment: its impossible you are doing something wrong
`def dtypes: Array[(String, String)] = schema.fields.map { field =>
    (field.name, field.dataType.toString)
  }` the way you are doing is much better way

Answer (score 4):

Note that print format in scala needs the %s, in python you can use {}

This should work:

```
 df.dtypes.foreach {  f =>
      val fName = f._1
      val fType = f._2
      if (fType  == "StringType") { println(s"STRING_TYPE") }
      if (fType  == "MapType") { println(s"MAP_TYPE") }
      //else {println("....")}
      println("Name %s Type:%s - all:%s".format(fName , fType, f))

    }
```

Comment: thats what i said in Comment :CopyPaste

Comment: How do i get the value of field f?